# Symfony Framework 2 and Eclipse: Error on 'factory' element in appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml

Tags: xml, eclipse, symfony

When I import a Symfony project I get the folowing error inside my appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'factory'. One of
>   '{"hxxp://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":file,
>   "hxxp://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":argument,
>   "hxxp://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":configurator,
>   "hxxp://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":call,
>   "hxxp://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":tag,
>   "hxxp://symfony.com/schema/dic/services":property}' is expected.

What is the cause and how could I solve that?

Note: I replaced 'http' by 'hxxp' because I don't have reputation enough. :(